# BitBucket.org - limitations only number of users?

Tags: git, mercurial, bitbucket

BitBucket now states that they offer unlimited repositories (Git and Mercurial) with the only limitation on number of users (5 for free account.)  Are there are known file-size, or repository-size limitations?  It seems 'too-good-to-be-true'...

I have created 5 private repos so far and haven't had any issues but I'd like to know what limits lie ahead. I didn't want to simply upload a ton of files to test out their limits...(I've attempted to post a message on their forums a few days ago but it hasn't been approved for release apparently.)

Comment: Confirmed that this is the case with BitBucket support.  They simply keep an eye out for abuse.  (For those people that want to use the service as a mirror of their music collection was their example.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As far as I know, the number of users is the only limit, and it's only the users that can access your **private** repositories.

You can create an unlimited number of private and public repositories, and an unlimited number of users can access your public repositories.
The only limitation is that no more than five users can access your private repositories.

Quote from [Bitbucket's "Plans" page](https://bitbucket.org/plans):

> **What is a user?**
>
> Someone with read or write access to one of your private repositories.